# Accessing a component in a ViewModel C#

Tags: c#, xaml, viewmodel

I have a class that extends `ViewModelBase` in C#. There is already a trigger on a checkbox:

```
public bool PrintPackingCode
{
    get
    {
        return this.reportConfiguration.PrintPackingCode;
    }

    set
    {
        this.reportConfiguration.PrintPackingCode = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("PrintPackingCode");
    }
}
```

I want to hook into that event and render a `GroupBox` to disable, yet I can't find a way to access the GroupBox. In the `.xaml` I gave my Box a name of `PackingcodeGroupBox`. All methods and hint I found weren't aplieable. My tries inculded:

```
Direct Access: PackingcodeGroupBox.Enabled = false;
Using a x:Name
this.Resources["mykey"]
```

Here some more Code:

```
//At program start assign the view it's view model:
new SmlKonfigurationWindow(new SmlKonfigurationWindowVm(reportConfiguration, smlKonfigurationDialogVm));

public SmlKonfigurationWindow(ISmlKonfigurationWindowVm viewModel)
{
   this.DataContext = viewModel;
   this.viewModel = viewModel;

   this.InitializeComponent();
   this.ShowDialog();
}
```

The xaml:

```
<CheckBox Content="Content" IsChecked="{Binding Path=PrintPackingCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="PrintPackingCode"/>
<GroupBox Header="Verpackungscode" Name="VerpackungscodeGroupbox">
   //Stuff to be disabled                      
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: Why don't you bind GroupBox.IsEnabled to this property?

Comment: I would, if you'd knew how it works

Comment: Post some xaml snippets from you code and show us the code where you assign the viewModel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IsEnabled is ambiental property which means that if you disable the GroupBox all controls inside that group box will also be disabled.

Try to add a binding on GroupBox like so:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding PrintPackingCode}"
```

You can also bind IsEnabled to check box if you give name to the check box.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" .../>
<GroupBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=myCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your vm create a new property say

```
private bool _isGroupEnabled;

public bool IsGroupEnabled
{
    get
    {
        return _isGroupEnabled;
    }

    set
    {
        _isGroupEnabled = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("IsGroupEnabled");
    }
}
```

Now tie into the notify process by adjusting your `set` for `PrintPackingCode`

```
   set
    {
        this.reportConfiguration.PrintPackingCode = value;
        IsGroupEnabled = !value; // reverse of packing to enable/disable.
        this.OnPropertyChanged("PrintPackingCode");
    }
```

Now bind your groupbox as such:

```
isEnabled = "{Binding IsGroupEnabled}"
```